# Fetch returns string instead of JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json, reactjs, serialization

In the code below `data` variable is a **simple string, not json** as I wish it to be.
Here is a client code:

```
const battleId = useSelector(selectBattle);
const [waitingBattle, setWaitingBattle] = useState(
    {
        ProcessingBattleDateModified: 30,
        CharactersInBattle: {}
    }
); 
   
fetch('https://localhost:44362/battles/GetWaitingRoomBattle/' + battleId, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(response => response.json()).then((data) => {
    setWaitingBattle(data);
    console.log(data);
})
```

You may notice that I'm using `response.json()` as it was suggested in other questions.

Here is my server endpoint:

```
[HttpGet("GetWaitingRoomBattle/{battleId}")]
public JsonResult GetWaitingRoomBattle(Guid battleId)
{
BattleEntity battle = _battleService.GetBattle(battleId);

 return new JsonResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(battle));
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the server is actually returning anything? What's in the network tab of the debugger console? Check the response data.

Comment: Your server is serialising the response data twice... If you deserialize it only once you get a string.

Comment: You should do `return new JsonResult{ Data = battle};`

Comment: Yes, server returns object as a string. Yes it was serialized twice that is the mistake. No I can't do JsonResult{ Data = battle}, as I want to use Newtonsoft Serializer.

Comment: You configure newtonsoft.json as default json serializer. https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/19/using-newtonsoft-json-in-net-core-3-projects/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to return Content, instead of JsonResult:

```
return Content( JsonConvert.SerializeObject(battle), "application/json" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do JSON.parse(data) like below code

```
const parsedData = JSON.parse(data)
```

Now you can get whatever key want like below line of code.

```
console.log(parsedData.Status) // 3
```